# Identify this set - bags with white, grey, brown and blue bricks

Tags: set-identification

Found these two bag from a box of toys given by friend And they don’t have any idea what set the bags belong to[image].
The QR code on the bag shows 6172092, googled it but no luck. Can anyone help? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 23):

I can see a [blue 4x4x6 corner door frame](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28327&idColor=7), and a [10x10 black net](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71155) (inside the [cardboard box labeled "6124286"](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?P=6124286)). That's enough to identify the set as [60174-1 Mountain Police Headquarters](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60174-1).

[image: set image]